# Android: How to Add Static row in list view

Tags: android, listview

Android: How to Add Static row in list view 
I have a requirement where i need to add the Static row as first row in list view

Thanks in advance for help..

Answer (score 3):

See [ListView.addHeaderView(android.View.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)).

You can add static headers and footers this way.

Comment: That's not strictly true. They are part of the list and scroll with the list contents. Since the person asking the question has not defined what a "static row" is, it is tough to say if `addHeaderView()` will fit the need. If the goal is a static header, something that does not scroll with the list, you just have to put it outside of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also got confused with view added with addHeaderView being scrolled out of screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the the ListView layout just like any other layout and add everything you need to the layout design.

for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.91" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:layout_weight="0.91"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to scroll along with the `ListView`, then place a separate view before the `ListView`. Might go like this:

```
<include layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" android:id="@+id/header"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ListView inside an LinearLayout with orientation="vertical".

Inside LinearLayout, put your static elements above (for header), or below (for footer) the ListView.